# jQuery validation errors with certain URLs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I've been looking for an answer for this for a while now and wondering if anyone has had the same issue.

The jQuery.validation plugin works fine, normally, just there's a few URLs that it doesn't validate properly and I'm seriously struggling to figure out why (or a valid work-around).

Normal URLs work fine, such as http://www.play.com, but the following URL will always fail to validate:

> http://www.play.com/DVD/Blu-ray/4-/21404340/Transformers-3-Dark-Of-The-Moon-3D/Product.html?searchstring=&searchtype=allproducts&searchsource=2&searchfilters=ae212{644651}%2bc{600}%2b&urlrefer=search

I'm guessing due to the { } characters.

I'm using the generic validation plugin usage:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});
```

Any insight into a fix for this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes, those characters are invalid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) One option you may wish to adopt is have an on change event on your URL input that replaces the current value with the URI encoded value.

```
$('.url-field').change(function() { $(this).val(encodeURI($(this).val())); });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does  not work, URLs get converted to something such as: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.play.com

Comment: Sorry, you want `encodeURI`. That will preserve the valid parts of the original URL.